# AttributeError: module 'telegram' has no attribute 'Bot'

Tags: python, api, telegram, attributeerror

I am using python and getting this error.

1. import telegram
2. telegram.Bot(token = '###############')

When I run this, appears: 
"AttributeError: module 'telegram' has no attribute 'Bot'"
Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: How did you install the package? Notice that there are a number of Telegram related packages available at PyPI, and many of them do not have the API that you're looking for.

Comment: Packages that give you the `Bot` class would be for example `telegram-bot` or `python-telegram-bot`, but we would need to know which one you intend to use

Comment: I did: "pip install telegram".

Comment: As I understand it now I should have done: "pip install telegram-bot"? Or better inspect which package I download and use.

Answer (score 16):

I assume you're referring to [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Introduction-to-the-API#hello-telegram) and that you solely use `python-pip` for package installation (and not your OS's package manager):

1. Ensure that you don't have colliding telegram packages installed:

```
~> pip3 list | grep -i telegram
python-telegram-bot 11.1.0
```

2. Force reinstall:

```
pip install --user --force-reinstall python-telegram-bot
```

3. Ensure that you don't accidentally have a `telegram.py` within your project.

Comment: yup! I had to reinstall. Accidently I had installed telegram pip and uninstalled which seems to have messed up the python-telegram-bot package.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you've installed the `telegram` package (according to the comments). Uninstall that one, and then you need to go and choose one that gives you the `Bot` class instead. For example:

- [python-telegram-bot](https://pypi.org/project/python-telegram-bot/)
- [telegram-bot](https://pypi.org/project/telegram-bot/)

Looks to me like the first one is more developed (the second one hasn't been touched in a while), but they have different licenses. Explore the options!

Answer (score 2):

Note that your file name (.py) does not the same with your package name.

Comment: Dont name your file telegram.py or it wont work LOL this happened to me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same issue and founded comment in [releated GitHub issue](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/issues/817#issuecomment-328762020) that if you run code in `test.py` file you will have this issue. Maybe it will solve the issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PyCharm, and you're new to programming, to add the module, you need to add it to your project here:
[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).